# Initialize keras model and wait for prediction call

Tags: python, keras, wait

I have the trained keras model. I want to create a script which initialize this model and wait to call of prediction.

The NeuralNet class is implemented like this

```
class NeuralNet(object):
def __init__(model):
    self.model = model
    self.model.compile(……..)
def predict(x)
    return self.model.predict(x)
```

I need to have something like two scripts. The first one will initialize the model and wait for calls

```
# main script
neural_net = NeuralNet(model)
wait()
```

The second script will address to the first script and call only method predict

```
# predict call
y = neural_net.predict(x)
return y
```

The idea is that I want to initialize the keras model only one time and then only make predictions without time loss for initialization.

I searched for different types of waiting and calling by events but could not understand how realize this case. I suppose that it is possible. Please give me advice in what direction to look.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It sounds like you're looking for a client-server model, where the server initializes the neural net once, serves an endpoint for predictions, and the second script calls the server. Unless `x` is a very large tensor, a HTTP server would suit this well.